# Selection of different number of variables for a model in a dataframe 

Tags: r, variables, dataframe

I have very large dataframe and I need to choose variable number satisfying certain criteria for analysis (for example variables in linear model). The following small data illustrates my data.

```
set.seed (1234) 
mydf <- data.frame (Id = c("dis", 1:5),

V1.a = c(0,sample(c(0, 1,2), 5, replace = T)),V1.b = c(0,sample(c(0, 1,2), 5, replace = T)),
V2.a = c(1.5,sample(c(0, 1,2), 5, replace = T)),V2.b = c(1.5,sample(c(0, 1,2), 5, replace = T)),
V3.a = c(2.0,sample(c(0, 1,2), 5, replace = T)),V3.b = c(2.0,sample(c(0, 1,2), 5, replace = T)),
V4.a = c(5.0,sample(c(0, 1,2), 5, replace = T)),V4.b = c(5.0,sample(c(0, 1,2), 5, replace = T)),
V5.a = c(6.0,sample(c(0, 1,2), 5, replace = T)),V5.b = c(6.0,sample(c(0, 1,2), 5, replace = T)),
V16a = c(11.0,sample(c(0, 1,2), 5, replace = T)),V6.b = c(11.0,sample(c(0, 1,2), 5, replace = T)),
V7.a = c(12.0,sample(c(0, 1,2), 5, replace = T)),V7.b = c(12.0,sample(c(0, 1,2), 5, replace = T)),
V8.a = c(3.0,sample(c(0, 1,2), 5, replace = T)),V8.b = c(3.0,sample(c(0, 1,2), 5, replace = T)))
```

Printed data:

```
   Id V1.a V1.b V2.a V2.b V3.a V3.b V4.a V4.b V5.a V5.b V6a V6.b V7.a V7.b V8.a V8.b
1 dis    0    0  1.5  1.5    2    2    6   6    7    7   11   11   12   12    3    3
2   1    1    2  1.0  1.0    2    0    0    1    2    1    2    0    0    2    0    2
3   2    1    2  2.0  0.0    2    0    2    1    2    1    0    0    2    1    1    1
4   3    2    0  1.0  2.0    1    1    1    0    2    0    1    2    0    2    1    0
5   4    0    1  1.0  1.0    1    1    0    1    0    2    2    2    2    1    0    2
6   5    1    0  2.0  2.0    0    2    1    2    1    1    1    0    2    2    2    2
```

Here is what I aim to do:

(1) Sort the columns by value in first row - smaller to larger (i.e.  dis) except for the ID column. Consider first row while shorting the dataframe

```
   Id   V1.a V1.b V2.a V2.b V3.a V3.b V4.a V4.b V5.a V5.b V6a V6.b V7.a V7.b V8.a V8.b
 1 dis    0    0  1.5  1.5    2    2    6   6    7    7   11   11   12   12    3    3
```

The columns (variables) are in order except V8.a and V8.b. The shorted data should be in order of:

```
   Id   V1.a V1.b V2.a V2.b V3.a V3.b V8.a V8.b V4.a V4.b V5.a V5.b V6a V6.b V7.a V7.b 
 1 dis    0    0  1.5  1.5    2    2   3   36   6    7    7   11   11   12   12
```

(2) Then calculate the di
fference between adjacent variables by difference in value in first row. For example, for V1a and V1b the difference is 0 and for V1.b and V2.a the difference is 1.5 - 0 = 1.5

difference between adjacent variables based on the row1

```
V1.a - V1b   V1.b- V2.a  V2.a - V2b  V2.b - V3.a    V3.a - V3.b
    0-0      0 - 1.5    1.5 - 1.5     1.5 - 2        2-2
```

and so on ...

(3) Start making models unless the difference calculated as in (2) between adjacent variables will be less than 2. Once the difference is greater than 2, a new model will be created and the process is continued unless end of the data file. The first row will not be included in model.

```
mydf1 =  mydf[-1,]   
model1 <- lm(Id ~ V1.a + V1.b + V2.a + V2.b + V3.a + V3.b + V8.a + V8.b, data = mydf1)
model2 <- lm(Id ~ V4.a + V4.b +  V5.a +  V5.b, data = mydf1)
model3 <- lm(Id ~ V6.a + V6.b + V7.a + V7.b, data = mydf1)
```

How can I automate this process?

***Edits: following the answer***

```
 d = mydf
> d
  Id V1.a V1.b V2.a V2.b V3.a V3.b V4.a V4.b V5.a V5.b V16a V6.b V7.a V7.b V8.a
1  0    0    0  1.5  1.5    2    2    5    5    6    6   11   11   12   12    3
2  1    1    2  1.0  0.0    1    2    1    2    0    1    1    2    0    1    1
3  2    1    1  2.0  2.0    1    2    0    1    0    1    1    1    0    2    0
4  3    0    0  1.0  2.0    2    0    2    2    2    2    2    1    1    2    0
5  4    0    2  0.0  2.0    2    2    1    1    2    2    2    1    2    1    0
6  5    2    1  2.0  0.0    2    0    1    1    0    1    0    0    0    2    1
  V8.b
1    3
2    2
3    0
4    2
5    0
6    2
>  d <- d[,order(d[1,-1])]
> d
  Id V1.a V1.b V2.a V2.b V3.a V7.b V8.a V3.b V4.a V4.b V5.a V5.b V16a V6.b V7.a
1  0    0    0  1.5  1.5    2   12    3    2    5    5    6    6   11   11   12
2  1    1    2  1.0  0.0    1    1    1    2    1    2    0    1    1    2    0
3  2    1    1  2.0  2.0    1    2    0    2    0    1    0    1    1    1    0
4  3    0    0  1.0  2.0    2    2    0    0    2    2    2    2    2    1    1
5  4    0    2  0.0  2.0    2    1    0    2    1    1    2    2    2    1    2
6  5    2    1  2.0  0.0    2    2    1    0    1    1    0    1    0    0    0
```

Ordering is not working for V7.a !

Comment: What does "smaller to larger (i.e. dis) except for the ID column" mean? What column should we sort by, and what is "dis"?

Comment: The "models" look weird: the response variable is factor...

Comment: @DavidRobinson please see my edits to clarify your questions

Comment: @VincentZoonekynd yes that is not what I want, but as I entered dis in first column the response was converted to factors. Probably I need de(?) factorization.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Order the columns so that the first row be in ascending `order`:

```
d <- d[,c(1,1+order(d[1,-1]))]
```

Compute the differences `d[1,i] - d[1,i-1]` (only for the first row):

```
d[1,-1] <- c(0, diff( drop(as.matrix(d[1,-1])) ))
```

Group the variables into blocks: add them one at a time, and start a new group if the difference computed at the previous step is 2 or more.

```
i <- 1+which( d[1,-1] >= 2 )
i <- data.frame( begin=c(2,i), end=c(i-1,dim(d)[2]) )
```

Compute the models, in a loop, creating a new data.frame each time:

```
models <- list()
for(k in 1:dim(i)[1]) {
  tmp <- d[-1, c(1, i$begin[k] : i$end[k])]
  tmp$Id <- as.numeric(as.character(tmp$Id))
  models[[k]] <- lm(Id ~ ., data=tmp)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for great answer, I am surprised to see the order is not working for V7.b which as value of 12 ! see my edits